# Finding min and max value in a random array

Tags: c++, arrays, max, min

Working on an assignment that requires me to put in some functions (finding max/min value, sum and average value of random numbers in an array), I've managed to complete all of them but for min value I'm getting a value of -2145379808. I'm not sure where I've messed up and I would appreciate the help. 
Code so far:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    {
        cout << "Enter array size " << endl;
    }
    float avg;
    float sum;
    int size;
    cin >> size;
    int array[size]; 
    int max = array [0];
    int min = array [0];
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (int i = 1; i < size + 1; i++)
    {
        array[i] = 1+rand()%100 ;
        sum += array[i];
        cout << "number " << i << " = "<< array[i] << endl;
    }
    for (int x = 1; x < size; x++){
        if (array[x] > max){
            max = array[x]; 
        }
         if (array[x] < min){
            min = array[x]; 
        }
    }
    cout << "\nmax = " << max << endl;
    cout << "\nmin = " << min << endl;
    cout << "\nsum = "<< sum << endl;
    cout << "\navg = " << sum / size << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are not initializing your variables. Always initialize your vairables. And you are off by one. Indexing out of bounds is undefined.

Comment: I thought the joy of C++ was to use the much-vaunted STL. See the section entitled `Example` after the section entitled `Second Version` here... http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element

Comment: `cin >> size; int array[size]; ` - That is not standard C++, and never will be (for good reason).  Use `std::vector<int>`

Comment: You *could* just use [std::nth_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) and get min and max in just two lines of resdable code. Or even better, use [std::minmax](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in following lines:

```
float avg;
float sum;
...
int max = array [0];
int min = array [0];
```

Because at this point the value at `array [0]` are *garbage value*.
To correct your code change this line as following (also include `climits` header file). Also, change loops index accordingly:

```
float avg = 0;
float sum = 0;
...
int max = INT_MIN;
int min = INT_MAX;
```

Following is corrected code(some changes made for optimization). See it working [here](https://ideone.com/9epFax):

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    {
        cout << "Enter array size " << endl;
    }
    float sum = 0;
    int size;
    cin >> size;
    int array[size]; 
    int max = INT_MIN;
    int min = INT_MAX;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        array[i] = 1+rand()%100 ;
        sum += array[i];
        cout << "number " << i << " = "<< array[i] << endl;

        if (array[i] > max){
            max = array[i]; 
        }
         if (array[i] < min){
            min = array[i]; 
        }
    }
    cout << "\nmax = " << max << endl;
    cout << "\nmin = " << min << endl;
    cout << "\nsum = "<< sum << endl;
    cout << "\navg = " << sum / size << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Setting `max` and `min` to the uninitialised element of `array` is never going to end well. On this note, you also need to initialise `sum`. You may as well remove `avg` since you don't use it.

You need to set `max` and `min` to the first element of `array` once you know what it is. Crudely, you could set `max` to `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` and `min` to `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`.

Note also that the *bounds* of `array` are `array[0]` to `array[size - 1]`. Therefore you need to revisit the indexing in your loops.

Then once you have it working, bin it, and use `std::vector<int>`, and things like `minmax_element`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element

Comment: @user463035818: Ha, let's publish jointly!

Comment: sometimes i have hard times to fix something at work, so it is always a pleasure to fix somehting here ;)

Comment: @AluanHaddad: Very true, C++ ain't Fortran.

Answer (score 0):

To insure your `max` and `min` are initialized correctly, C++ provides `std::numeric_limits` for all types. They each have `max()` and `min()` member functions to return the `max` and `min` value for the type. In any code you want to find a maximum and minimum, you want to first initialize your maximum to the minimum of the type and vice versa. That way any value will be larger than your `min` and smaller than your `max`.

You do that with `std::numeric_limits` similar to:

```
int min = std::numeric_limits<int>::max()
int max = std::numeric_limits<int>::min()
```

Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Provided the array has been initialised, surely it is just as legitimate to set your min and max to the first element of the array and iterate over the remaining elements, as it is to set your min and max to the extrema of their types?